# Implementing environment variables in simple linux shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, environment-variables, getenv

I am to program a simple shell in linux that can implement various stuffs including environment variables. I tried printing these variables using `getenv` but I have some problems. `getenv` always return `NULL` even if the user types a correct variable like `$HOME` for example. Here is my code

```
int i = 0;
if(strcmp(cmdArgv[i], "echo") == 0){
                char *variable;
                for(i = 1; cmdArgv[i] != NULL; i++){
                    variable = getenv(cmdArgv[i]);
                    if(!variable){
                        puts("not a variable");
                           printf("%s ", cmdArgv[i]);
                        }else{
                            puts("a variable");
                            printf("%s ", variable);
                        }
                   }
                   printf("\n");
                   exit(0);
               }
```

It doesn't enter into the `else` condition. For example if the user types `echo ls $HOME`. This input is parsed into the `cmdArgv` which is a `char **`. Then the output I have is

```
not a variable
ls
not a variable
$HOME
```

BUT `$HOME` is a variable so maybe my implementation of `getenv` isn't right. Any ideas as to what seem to be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable is called `HOME`, not `$HOME`. (The latter is your shell's syntax for *expanding* the variable.)

Comment: Just making it a little more obvious: getenv() accepts the environment variable without the $ sign.

Comment: @kerrek Oh yeah... you're right. I'll have to `putenv` VAR for $VAR to be a variable. I mixed the notion of having a `$` sign and not having it. I feel so stupid for seeing this. Thanks.

Comment: I have another question. Why is it that when you type `echo $HOME` in the linux terminal, it still treats it as a `HOME` variable?

Comment: @mkab: The variable is always called `HOME`. The dollar sign tells the shell that the next word is the name of a variable and makes it expand it. Try `echo HOME` to see the difference.

Comment: @mkab As it says in the answer, `$HOME` is the syntax used to expand a shell variable. "the linux terminal" is presumably running a linux shell, so when you type `"echo $HOME"`, the shell expands the HOME variable *before* invoking the echo command. Your "simple shell" isn't following this principle, it is expanding variables inside the echo command itself, which is not "simple" at all.

Comment: @mkab 'I'll have to putenv VAR for $VAR to be a variable' -- no, if you putenv("VAR=foo"), then getenv("VAR") will return "foo". The '$' is, again, *shell* syntax. When you type $VAR somewhere on the command line (outside of single quotes), you are telling the shell to replace it with getenv("VAR").

Comment: @jim: So for my shell I'd have to treat the case when the user types `$HOME`? Like i'd have to manually separate the `$` from the rest of the variable? Or is there a function that does it already apart from `getenv`?

Comment: @mkab: You need to parse the input and find all `$` and see if they are not escaped or single-quoted and then look at the rest of the token(s) following to figure out what to expand them to. After this is done you execute the resulting line. I recommend you read the source of an existing shell, such as `ash`; it will be instructive.